Update agent distribution list
Requirement: Check distribution lists of all OBIEE agents based off a lookup table. If the email is not present in the lookup table, the email should be removed off the distribution list.
How can this be achieved without having to create a conditional analysis on all agents?

Very simple: It can't be done without a conditional analysis because that's not how the tool works.
If you want such a check its easiest to implement it on your email server and filter there.
